# Location (X,Y) for UI

Tags: powershell

I have a form already, but needing a UI.PromptForChoice location moved else where as it's set in the background of the forms.
I've tried .TopMost and .Location/.Location.X and Y.
Just testing the code below separately to try and get it to (0,0) for default location.

Also, can I remove the .FormBorderStyle on it as well?

I can move the forms some where else, but that would be last resort as I have them side by side (needing two forms).

```
$title    = 'Admin Confirmation'
$question = 'Are you sure you want to proceed?'
$choices = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]
$choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&Yes'))
$choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&No'))

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
$Host.Location.X = 0
$Host.Location.Y = 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to bring the prompt to the foreground? On top of the form?

Comment: Does the main form has `topmost=$true`?

Comment: I have one form that it true for topmost. The other form is side by side with location. I have a function for a Yes/No Argument List for a confirmation I want to be TopMost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure you can use `$Host.UI.PromptForChoice` when working with WinForms. I usually use a function called Show-MessageBox from the PowerShell Gallery, it's really easy to use, you can download it from here https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FpsGeneral/1.0.21053.1/Content/Functions%5CShow-MessageBox.ps1.

Here is an example of how it looks and how you can use it. First you can place this function on the same folder as your main script and call it with `. "$PSScriptRoot\Show-Message.ps1"`

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

. "$PSScriptRoot\Show-Message.ps1"

$mainForm=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainForm.StartPosition='CenterScreen'
$mainForm.Icon=[System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$PSHOME\PowerShell.exe")
$mainForm.KeyPreview=$True
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle='Fixed3D'
$mainForm.Text='Test'
$mainForm.ClientSize=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,300)

$testChoiceBtn=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$testChoiceBtn.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
$testChoiceBtn.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($mainForm.Width-150),($mainForm.Height-100))
$testChoiceBtn.Text="Test Choice"
$testChoiceBtn.Add_Click({
    $messageHash=@{
        Title="Admin Confirmation"
        Message="Are you sure you want to proceed?"
        Icon="Question"
        Buttons="YesNo"
    }

    $decision = Show-MessageBox @messageHash
    Write-Host $decision
})
$mainForm.Controls.Add($testChoiceBtn)

$mainForm.Add_Shown({$mainForm.Activate()})
$mainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Here is how it would look:

[image: testform with show-messagebox]

Comment: It would work if I was able to download from Powershell Gallery. My job only has a collection of allowed modules that are able to be installed. Will upvote though. So thank you!

Comment: This is not a module tho, its a simple function. You could copy-paste the code in a ps1 :P